# How to add text prediction support to android ime?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have developed a Bengali fixed layout softkeyboard for android and now want to add text prediction to it, how can i achieve this? Any pointer would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write your own text prediction engine from scratch. Android does not provide one for you.

Here is a very brief overview:

1. Find a word frequency list on the web (many exist for English, not
   sure about Bengali)
2. Put it in an Sqlite database
3. Override InputMethodService.onKey() and get the string the user is currently typing
4. As the user types, query the Sqlite db for words that start with that string, sorted by frequency
5. Display the results in a View above the keyboard (check out the CandidateView class in the Softkeyboard sample in the Android SDK).

Good luck!

Comment: Thnx, I used Lexicographic ordering for prediction as i am not sure about frequency of words and provided a way for users to insert new words to SQLite dictionary along with my few pre-entered words. But I have found (.dict) file of both bangla & English dictionary, How can I use these files in place of my SQLite dictionary?

Comment: Sorry Imran I don't know what a dict file is but I suggest you find a way to port it to sqlite instead of accessing it directly in Android. Sqlite is native to Android and will probably work much faster.

Comment: Hmm I am also comfortable with SQLite but adding words one by one is very monotonous, I have some binary dictionary converted to .mp3 format but can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use AutoCompleteTextView ? ..hv a look here...

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html

Comment: Thnx for ur answer, i know about AutoCompleteTextView but my softkeyboard is a service and works system wide, so there is no activity + i need to use dictionary to show predictive text in the candidate view....